# FromName System String in MobileConnect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

We have a use case where we would like to retrieve the From Name via AMPscript code executed within a MobileConnect SMS message.

We were looking [here](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings/) for a system string to no avail.

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: there isn't one